# Node CPU usage/load spiking

Tags: java, performance, jboss, jboss6.x, java-threads

I have a number of nodes that are running JBoss 6 on it and an application hosted on it. Lately, I have seen that most/all of them have been have been complaining about high CPU usage and load and this results in the application slowing down.

So last night when the issue started to re-surface, I took a JAVA thread dump and see the following in nohup.out file.

```
"http-/0.0.0.0:8091-Poller" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4cb0171800 nid=0x2a1d in Object.wait() [0x00007f4d01dc0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x00000007426621b0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Poller)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Poller.run(JIoEndpoint.java:732)
  - locked <0x00000007426621b0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Poller)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4cc0056000 nid=0x2a18 waiting on condition [0x00007f4d022c5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1563)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ConnectionValidator" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4cb4051800 nid=0x2a12 waiting on condition [0x00007f4d023c6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  - parking to wait for  <0x0000000740c29b68> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2176)
  at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.validator.ConnectionValidator$ConnectionValidatorRunner.run(ConnectionValidator.java:263)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-/0.0.0.0:8091-8" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ce8046000 nid=0x2a2e in Object.wait() [0x00007f4d0055c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x00000007c1965448> (a com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.pollResponse(BasicInvocationFuture.java:265)
  - locked <0x00000007c1965448> (a com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.waitForResponse(BasicInvocationFuture.java:216)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocationFuture.java:193)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocationFuture.java:173)
  at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:404)
  at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.getInternal(MapProxySupport.java:223)
  at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:84)
  at com.ericsson.cac.sprint.adapters.hazelcast.HazelHelper.getObjectFromMap(HazelHelper.java:97)
  at com.ericsson.cac.sprint.adapters.hazelcast.CacheAOP.testAop(CacheAOP.java:415)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor126.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
  at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
  at com.ericsson.cac.sprint.adapters.QueryUsageProxyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21767524.queryPrepaidBalanceAndThresholdInfo(<generated>)
  at com.ericsson.cac.sprint.selfcare.workflow.throttling.ThrottlingWorkflowImpl.getThrottleInfo(ThrottlingWorkflowImpl.java:127)
  at com.ericsson.sprint.msdp.selfcare.controllers.abstracts.AbstractMyAccountController.usage(AbstractMyAccountController.java:529)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor173.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)

"hz._hzInstance_1_prod.event-5" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4cc8707000 nid=0x2abb waiting on condition [0x00007f4c85fde000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  - parking to wait for  <0x000000074f0b9ef0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
  at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.run(StripedExecutor.java:173)


"hz._hzInstance_1_prod.event-4" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4cc8704800 nid=0x2aba waiting on condition [0x00007f4c860df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  - parking to wait for  <0x000000074f0ba1e8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
  at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.run(StripedExecutor.java:173)
```

and so many more errors like these one.

I have also attached the full Jboss dump

Any idea why this might be happening ?

Comment: have you tried to check memory leak of the dump i.e. using eclipse MAT. I would check first duplicate classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs a deep investigation in order to find out the root cause of the problem, there is no straight forward way that you can use to tell you what is the problem.

But here some guide you can go through your investigations:

In the thread dump show this

```
"http-/0.0.0.0:8091-8" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ce8046000 nid=0x2a2e in Object.wait() [0x00007f4d0055c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x00000007c1965448> (a com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.pollResponse(BasicInvocationFuture.java:265)
  - locked <0x00000007c1965448> (a com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.waitForResponse(BasicInvocationFuture.java:216)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocationFuture.java:193)
  at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocationFuture.java:173)
  at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:404)
  at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.getInternal(MapProxySupport.java:223)
  at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:84)
  at com.ericsson.cac.sprint.adapters.hazelcast.HazelHelper.getObjectFromMap(HazelHelper.java:97)
```

the stack tells that the thread is waiting for a object monitor, which means that another thread is using this object in synchronization context, you need to track the thread that locked that object and see what is currently doing, in there you can find what making that thread holding the object for too long.

You can use `TDA` the [Thread Dump Analyzer](https://java.net/projects/tda/downloads) to do it.

Also you may need to check the memory status.